# Building a SQL query - Return some rows once, some not

Tags: php, mysql, select, userid

I need to build a SQL query which is beyond my programming abilities. 
Okay, here is my request:

Let's say I have a table, with: id, **user_id**, **email** and **amount** columns. This query, should SELECT **user_id** only once! If I have matched user_id once, the query shall continue, but if the same user_id is matched again in another row, we should skip it.

Here comes the main problem...

Imagining that we grabbed user_id once, and skipped all same other rows with that user_id, now I need to **sum** all the contents from the **amount** column for the same user_id.

I think I complicated this a bit, I'll try illustrating my issue:

[image: illustration of my problem]

If this problem is not solvable via SQL only, then a PHP answer would work too.

I'm trying to create a list of users (no duplicate users) and add the amount they paid.

According to the image, **user_id *56*** paid **90.00** (12 + 45 + 33)

Can someone tell me a way how to achieve this?

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the name of the table is `users`

```
SELECT user_id, email, SUM(amount) FROM users GROUP BY user_id
```

Comment: Do you need to name the sum(amount), just curious?

SELECT user_id, sum(amount) as amount from users group by user_id;

Comment: @lc, I guess I was assuming the email column was unique to every user_id.

Comment: In my case txn_id is always unique, it has an unique index. Does this query select it the way I need?

Comment: which columns are you interested in selecting exactly? your question doesn't state that

Comment: Well, indirectly it does. I need user_id and mc_gross (amount).

Comment: @lc . . . That is simply false.  MySQL has the (mis)feature of Hidden Columns, which allows exactly this sort of query.  The email in the return is chosen arbitrarily from the rows in the group.